# Should SO provide in-line question templates to promote a balance between length of post and enough detail?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I post on StackOverflow I treat it very much as a last resort having exhausted my own, and those around me, knowledge. Hence, when I do post I like to include as much detail as possible. A thought did occur though - when is detail to the background of a question too much, ie when does detail cross the lines into being overly verbose and to discourage reading and increase bounce rate?

For example, I posted a question 13 hours ago about [Lync 2010 Contract Card integration into LOB Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341678/lync-2010-contract-card-integration-into-lob-application) but I do worry my post is overly detailed and hence discouraging a user to read it.

Should StackOverflow perhaps provided inline templates for creating the correct detail vs length post

While templates on a users first question would perhaps encourage better questions, I am suggesting it could be used at the other end of things as well - my hypothesis that too much info is equally as bad to receiving good answers. Perhaps an option to turn templates off after a given Rep score - saying this I have seen users with 4-5 figure rep asking bad questions.

Thoughts?

Comment: It would be extremely hard, if not impossible, to create a template that matches all cases. Even going for something that fits 90% of cases seems like an enormous amount of work. You can't apply the same template to all kinds of questions that can be asked on SO.

Comment: @l4mpi I agree, it would not be easy and would probably have multiple dimensions of complexity, but nothing worth doing ever is :-) There does seem to be a general problem on SO with bad questions not providing enough detail, but I have a feeling the opposite is also true (would be interesting for someone to run the stats) that too much info is also bad.

Comment: @gnat I think that is close, but not exactly the same. While templates on a users first question would perhaps encourage better questions, I am suggesting it could be used at the other end of things as well - my hypothesis that too much info is equally as bad to receiving good answers. Perhaps an option to turn templates off after a given Rep score - saying this i have seen users with 4-5 figure rep asking bad questions

Comment: One option is to write in an [*"inverted pyramid"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid) style, so that users can read the first paragraph to understand whether this is an appropriate question for them, then keep reading to gain progressively more detailed information.